# Something is broken

Tags: transitivity

How do you say "Since this thing is broken, I need to buy a new one."?

And, what are the differences between the following:

> この物が壊れましたから、新しいのを買わなきゃ。
>
> この物が壊れています、新しいのをかわなきゃ。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would like to talk about the phrase 「この[物]{もの}」.  We rarely, if ever, say it in a natural setting.  It is grammatical, but we just do not say it much.

Instead, you would simply say 「**これ**」 if you are holding the thing in your hand or pointing your finger to it.

You can also use 「**この + real name**」 as in 「このカメラ」、「このテレビ」, etc.

Your two sentences:

> 「この物が[壊]{こわ}れましたから、[新]{あたら}しいのを[買]{か}わなきゃ。」
>
> 「この物が壊れています、新しいのを買わなきゃ。」

are grammatical but not very natural-sounding if I were to speak strictly.

The only reason for the unnaturalness is your combined use of non-informal phrases (壊れましたから and 壊れています) and very informal phrase 「買わなきゃ」.

Your use of 「新しいの」 is excellent (and very natural).

My suggestion would be to use 「しまう」:

> Not so informal: 「これ（or この～～）が壊れて**しまった**ので、新しいのを買わなければなりません。」
>
> Informal: 「これ（or この～～）が壊れ**ちゃった**ので、新しいのを買わなきゃ。」

In meaning, 「しまった」＝「ちゃった」.  The latter is more informal/colloquial.

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways to say that. One is using から as you do in the first sentence.

The first sentence means "Since this thing is broken, I need to buy a new one." while the second means "This thing is broken, I need to buy a new one.".

The only problem that stands out in your sentence is you are mixing formal and popular way of speaking. 壊れました/壊れています is formal. 買わなきゃ is popular.